# Invalid character (CR or LF) found in method name in spring boot application

Tags: angularjs, spring

I am using spring boot MVC application running  on *localhost:8080*.

I want to access this from my Angularjs app placed in xampp htdocs folder running on *localhost/public*.

Cors in Angular service are enabled and working while am using this in Spring controller:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost/public", maxAge = 3600)
@RequestMapping("/application")
public class applicationController{

    @Autowired
    private applicationRepository applicationrepository;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<StudentApplication> list() {
        return  applicationrepository.findAll();
    }
 }
```

While accessing this endpoint i am getting this error:

```
Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character (CR or LF) found in method name
```

Any Help regarding this issue?

Comment: The error's coming from Tomcat and it's indicating that it has received an HTTP request with a method name (`GET`, POST`, etc) that contains an invalid character. How are you accessing the endpoint? It looks like a malformed HTTP request is being sent

Answer (score 0):

Since your localhost:8080 you should specify the port as well

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080/public", maxAge = 3600)
```

Let me know if this worked for you

Comment: no this isn' working but @CrossOrigin() worked for me when i send request to http://localhost:8080 from angualr.

Comment: can you change it to @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080", maxAge = 3600)

Comment: no it isn't working.any url m specifying is problemtic